# Restrict access to specific EC2 ports?

Tags: amazon-ec2, server-side

I'd like to restrict certain ports on my EC2 instance to require a login to access what's currently on the port (a rails app I'm building). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I presume you will either implement this with a web server or within your app. There is no generic ec2 specific way to do this.